# Plotting species abundance vs elevation with geom smooth and multiple y axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot species abundance (x-axis) against elevation (y-axis) and add a geom_smooth, but with multiple y-axis values for one x-axis value as the distribution is gaussian. Right now I have the elevation on the x-axis, but I want to rotate the plot/geom_smooth. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
data<-data.frame("n_observations"=c(10,30,50,40,10),"elevation"=c(100,200,300,400,500))

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(n_observations,elevation)) + #At the moment i have aes(elevation,n_observations)
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

Comment: `coord_flip()` in `ggplot2` would help you rotate the plot.

Comment: Awesome, this did the job perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to YH Jang a coord_flip() did the job:

```
data<-data.frame("n_observations"=c(10,30,50,40,10),"elevation"=c(100,200,300,400,500))

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(elevation,n_observations)) 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  coord_flip()
```